# PHP - Why does time() return different number of seconds than strtotime(date())

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, strtotime

I found out that these two returns different numbers - but both should give a timestamp.

```
strtotime( date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ); //currently 1447570497
time(); //currently 1447613697
```

The difference is exactly 12 hours (43200 seconds), also same thing happens for:

```
(new DateTime( date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ))->getTimestamp(); //acts like strtotime+date
(new DateTime("now"))->getTimestamp(); //acts like time()
```

Why is this happening? (Since it's 12 hours it is probably not daylight-saving time issue)

Is it something with 24 vs 12 hours - modes?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: `h` is 1-12. So if you would have tested in in the morning, it would have worked :)

Comment: @Reeno ah thanks ! That was exactly my problem - it worked and then it didn't x) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `H` in `date()` to get the correct time after 12pm. Otherwise you will be off by 1 - 12 hours.

```
strtotime( date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ); //currently 1447570497
```